# Global variables in a header file

Tags: c, header-files

I was just wondering if you declare a variable in a header file like this

```
const static int START = 0;
```

would that variable (START) be considered global?

Comment: Just `#define START 0`. It's clearer and it avoids all the trickery with `const static` variables.

Answer (score 2):

If you define:

```
const static int START = 0;
```

at file scope, then `START` will have internal linkage and static duration due to `static`.

This means that each translation unit that includes the header will end up with a copy of the symbol and that each of them will live throughout the entire program.

Comment: so dose that mean that it would be global?

Comment: @cLax no. you'll have 2 variables with same name.

Comment: @cLax — Note that if a source file includes the header, it will get the variable `START` defined, whether it uses the value or not.  And if it doesn't get used, you'll likely get warnings about the unused variable.  (If you don't get the warning, you're probably not using your compiler with enough warning options enabled.)  Rule of thumb: don't define variables in headers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

Lets say you add that definition into 'myvar.h' and then you include that header file into 'main.c' and 'other.c'

All functions in 'main.c' and 'other.c' will know about the defined variable --so in a way, it is global.

But in fact there will be two different variables with the same name. Changes made by functions in 'main.c' won't be visible by functions in 'other.c' and vice versa.

That's because static variables defined outside of functions are considered 'local to the compilation unit'.

On the other hand, if you just remove the 'static' keyword, the variable will be defined twice (once for each compilation unit in which the header file is included) and the linker will emit a 'duplicate symbol' error.

Comment: You can't (shouldn't try to) make changes to a constant integer.

Comment: True, but the point is: the way it is defined, you'll end having two different copies of the variable allocated in the static segment.